# How to use \pgfmathfloattomacro to store computation values in a variable and reuse the variable

Tags: pgfkeys, pgfmath

I use `\pgfmath` for computation of floating point numbers a lot. But I want to store the result of each computation and store it in a variable and then use back to perform another floating point arithmetic.

```
The small signal parameters are given as,\\
$g_{m}=\dfrac{2I_{D}}{V_{OV}}$\; and\; $r_{o}=\dfrac{\lambda}{I_{D}}$\\
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=sci}
$g_{m1,2}=
\pgfmathparse{(2*0.75*pow(10,-3))/(0.25)}
\pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=2]{\pgfmathresult}$;

$r_{o3,4}=
\pgfmathparse{(1)/(0.2*1.5*pow(10,-3))}
\pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\pgfmathresult}
\pgfmathfloattomacro{\pgfmathresult}{\F}{\Mr3}{\Er3}
 \Mr3 \times  \pgfutilensuremath{10^{\Er3}}$;
```

and now I want to perform the following operation

```
$A=g_{m1,2}\cdot r_{o3,4}$
```

Also, I need a macro to pass in different values and get results onto different variables.

Comment: Why don't you just use a different macro so you aren't overwriting `\pgfmathresult`? I don't really understand the question, I guess. Can you make your fragment into an MWE?

Answer (score 1):

Store the intermediate results by `\let\XX{\pgfmathresult}` and then retrieve the results later whenever needed.
Note: There are few thinks that are to be kept in mind

1. The variable `\XX` should not contain any number.
2. Remove the local scope while defining. I.e., in the above code, I tried to use \let\XX within $ $(which actually act as a local scope).